# E-Ink screen pixel update

Tags: e-ink

How noisly common E-ink screens when they update pixel ? I mean do they have strobe signal or something like this, or they update exact pixel using pixel coordinates ?

Comment: can you comment downvote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can guess that someone thought you should have done a little research on your own and asked a more specific question. In particular, asking "how noisly" is not likely to get any good answers.

Comment: I did research and found nothing about the problem, more over - I not found such info for TFT displays too. As not native english I have not big vocabulare for this topic. And yes - I got answer I searched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only the regions of the screen that are changing require updating. Any pixels that are not changing do not require updating.

See http://www.eink.com/faq_matrix.html

---

[image]

[image]

See http://www.essentialscrap.com/eink/Driving_E_Ink_Displays.pdf

---

Whether E-ink pixels can be changed independently depends on the design of the control electronics of the specific display module that incorporates an e-ink panel.

You need to consult the data sheet for the specific e-ink product you intend to use.

Comment: it is on pixel itself, but what signal go from controller to e-ink matrix ? I asking to understand if it hard to combine resonator digitiser panel ([like here](http://www.tablet4u.co.uk/techinfo.html)) with e-ink display. (will display generate additional errors to the pen?)

Comment: http://essentialscrap.com/eink/electronics.html ok seems it answers the question